# Get selected option text and not value

Tags: jquery, html, multiple-select, multiple-select-query

I have a multiple select and I want to get selected **text** and not the **value**.

What I mean is this :

```
<option value="1100"> MH-03-P-9429</option>
```

And I want to get **MH-03-P-9429** as selected text, but when I do

```
$("#usersDropDown").multipleSelect('getSelects')
```

I get output as 1100 as shown in fiddle.

[Multiple Select Issue](https://jsfiddle.net/850xcwh8/1/)

Can anyone help me out here ?

How can I get selected option text and not the value ?

***NOTE :*** **.text()** and **.val()** doesn't work against getSelects

Comment: Need to raise event after selection [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/850xcwh8/2/#&togetherjs=g24REQzRF0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#usersDropDown").multipleSelect({
  placeholder: "Select Users",
  selectAll: true,
  width: "100%",
  filter: true,
});
$("#usersDropDown").on('change',function ()
{
  var getSelected = $("#usersDropDown").multipleSelect('getSelects', 'text');
  alert(getSelected)
});
```

Comment: Your code is already perfect in fiddle, just you need to pass 'text' as parameter to get text as above.

Answer (score 4):

Use this combination:

> ```
>  ("option:selected").text();
> ```

See [<kbd>FIDDLE</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/5b4h20wm/) and/or Snippet 2 for how it applies to your specific code.

**SNIPPET 1**

```js
$('#sel').on('change', function() {
  var txt = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
  $('output').val(txt);
});
```

```css
#sel {font:inherit}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='sel'>
<option>TEXT1</option>
<option>TEXT2</option>
<option>TEXT3</option>
<option>TEXT4</option>
</select>
<output></output>
```

**SNIPPET 2**

```js
$("#usersDropDown").multipleSelect({
  placeholder: "Select Users",
  selectAll: true,
  width: "100%",
  filter: true
});
$("#usersDropDown").on('change', function(e) {
  var getSelected = $("#usersDropDown").find("option:selected").text();
  alert(getSelected);

});
```

```html
<link href='https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/multiple-select/master/multiple-select.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<select id="usersDropDown" multiple="multiple" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Select Users">
  <option value="1100"> MH-03-P-9429</option>
  <option value="1101"> MH-03-A-2104</option>
  <option value="1102"> MH-03-PB-8413</option>
  <option value="1103"> MH-03-BP-3000</option>
  <option value="1104"> MH-03-PA-9400</option>
</select>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multiple-select/1.2.0/multiple-select.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#usersDropDown").multipleSelect({
  placeholder: "Select Users",
  selectAll: true,
  width: "100%",
  filter: true,
});

$("#usersDropDown").on('change',function ()
{

var textss= $(".ms-choice span:first").text();
alert(textss);
});
```

Use this to get all selected text https://jsfiddle.net/850xcwh8/4/